# how to achieve paging in a grid view in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging, custom-paging

I'm using ASP.net web application with c#. In my web application I have a webpage with a data grid view.

I'm using this method to bind data to data grid view

```
 public void fillGridByALLBDetails()
    {
        GVView01.DataSource = new LibraryCatalogueOP().getLibraryCatalogue();
        GVView01.DataBind();   
    }
```

I'm calling the data grid view bind method in the page load event like this.

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fillGridByALLBDetails();
            }
```

This is my business layer method to get the data.

```
     public DataTable getLibraryCatalogue()
{
    string myQuery1 = "EXEC SelectLibraryCatalogue";
    return new DataAccessLayer().ExecuteMyTable(myQuery1);
}
```

Sometimes my data grid loads a lots of data at once. I want to know how to achieve **PAGING** with this code.
Any code example would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `pagesize=10` (or 20 whatever size of page you want to display )property of gridview in designer page and provide `allowpaging=true` in designer you can get both properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this detailed example

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-in-ASPNet-GridView-Example.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the properties

```
  <asp:gridview id="GVView01" 
            allowpaging="true" 
            pagesize="15"
            runat="server">
```

you can use `pagesize="10"` (or 20 whatever size of page you want to display )property of gridview in designer page and provide `allowpaging="true"` ,  in designer you can get both properties

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"
    Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"  
    OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging"
    PageSize = "10" >
```

.
.
.

And now in order make the paging functionality work we will need to add the OnPageIndexChanging event of the GridView control

```
protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```